# Access denied on my remote server via ssh on windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, git

Hi everyone I'm trying to connect to my remote server using `ssh -i "my_keyprivate.pem" instance@ipaddr` but I get the error message **Permission denied (publickey)**
And when I do `ssh -vvv` I get this

```
$ ssh -vvv "my_keyprivate.pem" instnace@ipaddr
OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/c/Users/toto/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/c/Users/toto/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "my_openssh.pem" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup my_openssh.pem:22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname my_openssh.pem: Name or service not known
```

I allowed my user object to have full control,
Here is the content of my `C:\Users\toto\.ssh` folder

```
my_keyprivate.pem
known_hosts
```

I dont know where the problem is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The output of `ssh -vvv "my_keyprivate.pem" instnace@ipaddr` is useless because the command misses `-i` you used earlier.

Comment: "Permission denied (publickey)" means the server rejected the key. Apparently it's not properly configured to accept this exact key.